# How do I mock a single class static in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a class like this...

```
import axios frome "axios";
...
class A extends Component{
  constructor(){
    A.callUnmockable();
    ...
  }
  static callUnmockable(){
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  }
}
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to mock `callUnmockable` without mocking the entire class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it...

```
jest.spyOn(A,"callUnmockable").mockImplementation(() => null);
```